# google URL change

Tags: java, url

When I call this in java :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=MSFT");
URLConnection goog = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(goog.getInputStream()));
```

I get this as exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/finance/getprices%3Fq%3MSFTO%26
```

I don't have converted URL in my function because its generated automatically when my URL is called, My original URL is string after "continue=", how can I get it back from this URL?

EDIT :

Because I am calling this page again and again it generates this URL http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/finance/getprices%3Fq%3MSFTO%26 and it says :

Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot. 
If I copy paste URL after continue= it gives me actual content of page.

Comment: Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes, `503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).[2] Generally, this is a temporary state.
`

Answer (score 0):

503 is a response code which tells service is down or unavailabe

[wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

According to wikipedia

```
503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).[2] Generally, this is a temporary state.
```

I have tried your code and this is woriking fine (giving no exception)

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=MSFT");
    URLConnection goog = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(goog.getInputStream()));
    String temp;
    while((temp = in.readLine())!= null){
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and its return me

```
EXCHANGE%3DNASDAQ
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=570
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=960
INTERVAL=86400
COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=-240
a1370289600,35.59,35.63,34.83,34.92,51256272
1,34.99,35.74,34.771,35.62,65538438
2,34.78,34.89,34.43,34.6,46032657
3,34.96,35.11,34.49,34.84,37627133
4,35.67,35.78,35.06,35.25,40762249
7,35.47,35.65,35.14,35.51,35995223
8,34.84,35.18,34.68,35.05,39350316
9,35,35.27,34.85,35.14,37373032
10,34.715,35.02,34.59,34.99,45654803
11,34.4,34.6901,34.25,34.55,53116371
14,35,35.16,34.63,34.69,49672492
15,34.98,35.17,34.895,34.97,28622929
16,34.59,35.09,34.59,34.96,30820208
17,33.49,34.33,33.37,34.26,54496758
18,33.265,33.73,33.05,33.66,85338395
21,33.715,34.2,32.57,32.94,56113708
22,33.67,34.38,33.46,34.08,44073348
23,34.35,34.48,33.8875,34.12,48667834
24,34.62,34.78,34.5,34.52,28993542
25,34.545,34.79,34.34,34.38,65548196
28,34.36,34.99,34.33,34.75,31064000
```

So probably problem is that service is not available temporarily in your area.

Comment: Prob is I am calling this repeatedly so google checks after some time that URL is not hit by BOT, so it redirect to  http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://www.google.com/finance/getprices%3Fq%3MSFTO%26

Comment: Make some delay Thread.sleep(500) after each request, may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: Dear you cant override Google security

Comment: Even if I made it sleep for two minutes my URL is redirecting me to captcha page, but if I terminate the program and start again with in 5 seconds I am getting actual page. Why is that happening?

Comment: Are you opening your connection inside loop??? I mean this code should be inside loop block


URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=MSFT");

URLConnection goog = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(goog.getInputStream()));